# Server not accepting URL variables

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, laravel

I'm on DigitalOcean Ubuntu and using laravel framework, the server strangely refuse get variables, so `www.domain.com/?name=mohamed` when I check `$_GET['name']` I get nothing, what can be the cause of this problem?

htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Showing people some code, may shed some light on the subject, perhaps? ;-)

Comment: Try `var_dump($_GET)`.

Comment: It's an `^---^` invaluable tool

Comment: @EisaAdil I tried and it's empty, this is freaking strange, It's working on the local environment but not the live site.

www.domain.com/?name=mohamed
redirects to
www.domain.com/

and www.domain.com?name=mohamed
reads nothing in $_GET

Comment: how does it redirect? Show some code so we can take a look (`.htaccess` if you have it is probably where your problem is) `[QSA]` flag?

Comment: Here's the htaccess file:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

Comment: Try changing `RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]` to `RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]`

Comment: Still the same, maybe it's something in apache configs when I installed LAMp first

Answer (score 0):

By default, Laravel uses "pretty" URL schemes. Typically you would set up a route like

```
Route::get('user/{name}', function($name)
{
    return 'Hello, ' . $id . '!';
});
```

which would let you access a `$name` variable set to `mohamed` when you visit `/user/mohamed`. See the section on routing, specifically [route parameters](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters) in the [official documentation](http://laravel.com/docs).

Comment: Hello Chris, I'm familiar with that but I'm just diagnosing why it's acting this way!

Comment: Where is this question tagged as Laravel? :/

Comment: @FDL, good point, I have submitted an edit to the question adding this tag. Laravel is mentioned in the body of the question.

Comment: @Chris ah I didn't see it in the body, was just confused that's all :)

Comment: @MohamedSaid, are you trying to inspect `$_GET` from `index.php`, or from another script? Once the request has been parsed, I believe the request to the controller is dispatched via method calls, not via submitting another `GET` request.